# Center map based on some (x,y) in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates

I want to center and recenter the map loaded on QGIS using constantly changing (x,Y) Point. How should I do this using some code?

My GPS device will write (x,y) to a text file. From there I get (x,y) and plot two points at a time over a map on QGIS using below Code.

```
    QUrl url =  QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/mit/Desktop/Bagfiles/file1.txt");
    url.addQueryItem("delimiter",",");
    url.addQueryItem("xField", "x");
    url.addQueryItem("yField", "y");
    url.addQueryItem("crs","epsg:4723");
    while (true)
    {
    emit drawVectorLayer(QString::fromAscii( url.toEncoded() ), "layer", "delimitedtext");
   usleep(10000000);
    }
```

Now I want to center the map based on these values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set the extant rectangle to same the point it will recenter but not change the zoom or scale

```
 map_pos = QgsPointXY(x, y)
 rect = QgsRectangle(map_pos, map_pos)
 self.canvas.setExtent(rect)
 self.canvas.refresh()
```

I'm also curious why you are writing to a file and then redrawing that layer. That's pretty expensive if all you want to do is show a GPS location on the map.

You can have a look at some code that I wrote to see how to show a GPS marker on the map without having to write out to a layer first https://github.com/NathanW2/qmap/blob/master/src/qmap/gps_action.py

Comment: Thank you. I am writing to a file because my project needs that.

Comment: I done as you said. As soon as the point map_pos is changed the new map_pos point appears at the center of map. but map remains in older position until if it is clicked somewhere inside mapcanvas .

Comment: my problem is solved after refreshing my mapcanvas.i did it by following the link given by you in your answer. now somewhat i can understand python code :D . Thank you.